# Error running GlobalProtect in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dll

I am trying to run a GlobalProtect client from my school to connect to VPN. Installation works fine but when I run it I get this error:

[image]

I downloaded the [api-ms-win-shcore-scaling-l1-1-1.dll](https://www.dll-files.com/api-ms-win-shcore-scaling-l1-1-1.dll.html) and copy/paste it into the system32 folder. But now I get a different error:

[image]

It's a fresh windows install and I am not sure what to do.

**UPDATE**: how can I download version 5.0 or 5.1 when the [download page of Palo Also](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/globalprotect/5-1/globalprotect-app-user-guide/globalprotect-app-for-windows/download-and-install-the-globalprotect-app-for-windows.html#idf9d1968d-51fb-463b-8923-4c785cee5f18) says go go VPN server URL

[image]

Comment: The `api-ms-win-*` items tend to suggest that an application has been compiled with support for either Windows 8 or 10 (most likely 10) and your choices tend to be to use an older version of the application or to upgrade your operating system.

Comment: You'll have to download it on a different system or use a supported operating system. You may have to talk to your network administrators.

Comment: "how can I download version 5.0 or 5.1" - It probably isn't distributed by the company.  If the application is required for work, you should ask your network administrators for the installer, they are responsible for providing you the installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to download the 5.0 or 5.1 client.

From [Client compatibility](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/compatibility-matrix/globalprotect/where-can-i-install-the-globalprotect-app#id7a3c3401-b233-43b0-8d78-dfceab88798f_id0204a5d9-4857-4979-8fa0-14809d8e697b)

[image]